# Site name\logo in a panel pane?

Tags: panels

I want the site's name\logo to appear in a column in a Panels pane (instead of it's regular appearance in the header region). is there any way to achieve this without programing?

Comment: I don't have a good site to test with right away, but isn't there a pane already provided for the logo at least?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Go to the pane where you want the logo or site name. Click on the 'Add content' gear wheel and then you'll find the site name and logo under the 'Page elements' section.